# Why do I get ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have hosted my website on AWS. I did not get the connection timeout error when I had only one server instance with 5000 requests from Jmeter in one second. But received connection timeout error after I increased the instance to 4.

I am using AWS db.t2.small RDS instance. I saw from the blog that it can handle 150 concurrent connections.

this is my database config.

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
```

1. If this error comes when rails gets more than 5 requests at a time then why did it not happen when I had only one instance?
2. Database can have 150 concurrent connections. 4 instances with 5 pool thread would be 20 threads. It is way below the maximum limit. What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: What is the query that you are trying to execute that is raising this error?

Comment: i am querying 5 different active record models for generating the html template. i was load testing the endpoint with different urls. My webserver is puma with 1024 worker connections. But pool size is 5.

Comment: Can you try some simple query and not a heavy one which fetches data from so many models? Puma has a default timeout value of 60 secs. So in case your query runs for longer than that, it'll timeout. So you could try a small query, which would help us figure out whether its a problem with slow loading of code, or due to the change in your instance's config.